# Is there a way to Factory reset my HTC One M7?

Tags: factory-reset, htc-one

Is there a way to *Factory reset* my HTC One M7?

I want to completely wipe it and restore it to how it was when I first turned it on.

So all apps, pictures, phone numbers, music, everything gone.

Googling *Factory reset* is just showing me instructions on how to *Hard reset* the device as if it's stalled or frozen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Take your HTC One and tap on menu.
2. Then hit settings.
3. Go to general and choose “backup and factory reset”.
4. Pick “factory reset”.
5. Agree and wait while the hard is being completed.
6. Done.

This will completely wipe all information off your phone, texts, call logs, pictures, etc.  Make sure you back up all your information onto your sd card and remove it before starting this process.

[Source](http://www.android.gs/hard-reset-htc-one/)